# Django: using save(commit=false) when saving form extended from form.Forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a many-to-many field and in order to save the retrieved data from the form, initially, I have to save an instance of that table, otherwise, I get an error like:

> "Order: None" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

But the issue is when I have 2 save methods called, they also create 2 different logs(at the first `save()` it creates the instance and at the letter one it edits it) and this cause the chaos. Therefore, I want to be able to `commit=False` in the first one and finalize the save in the second `save()`. Commit is used for `ModalForm`, however, my form extends `form.Forms`.

## views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderAddForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        order = Order()
        order.user = request.user
        order.save()

        order.ordered_materials.set(form.cleaned_data['ordered_materials'])
        order.location = form.cleaned_data['location']
        order.note = form.cleaned_data['note']

        form.save()
else:
    form = OrderAddForm()
```

## forms.py

```
class OrderAddForm(forms.Form):
  ordered_materials = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
      queryset=Material.objects.all(),
  )
  location = forms.CharField()
  note = forms.CharField()

  ordered_materials.widget.attrs.update({'id': 'materialsid',
                                 'class': 'form-control',
                                 })
```

## models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)

ordered_materials = models.ManyToManyField('Material')
location = models.CharField(max_length=500)
note = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                        verbose_name="Note")

STATUS = (
    ('n', 'None'),
    ('a', 'Accepted'),
    ('r', 'Rejected'),
)

status_name = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                               choices=STATUS,
                               default='n')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Comment: Your `OrderAddForm` class inherits from `forms.Form` instead of `forms.ModelForm`. Therefore it doesn't have a `save()` method (unless you've added one and left it out of the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to save the object after setting the many-to-many field. Therefore you should be able to re-arrange your code so that you only call `save()` once.

```
if form.is_valid():
    order = Order()
    order.user = request.user
    order.location = form.cleaned_data['location']
    order.note = form.cleaned_data['note']
    order.save()

    order.ordered_materials.set(form.cleaned_data['ordered_materials'])
```